# How do I access my tuple that comes from a c# controller in angular?

Tags: c#, angular

Here is my backend. As you can see I try to return a tuple with a bool and a DataTable. The reason I want to do this, is because I want just one post method to do multiple things; I want the boolean so the user either gets authorized or not (based on their input in the frontend) and the DataTable so the user can retrieve their details on their profile, once authorized.

```
        public Tuple<bool, DataTable> Post(Gebruikers geb)
        {
            try
            {

                string query = @"select * from dbo.Gebruikers
                    where (Email = '" + geb.Email + @"' and Wachtwoord = '" + geb.Wachtwoord + @"')";

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MReserverenDB"].ConnectionString))
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.Fill(table);

                }
                string s = "";
               

                for (int i = 0; i <table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        s += table.Rows[i][j];
                        
                    }
                }
                
                return Tuple.Create(s != "", table);
                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Tuple<bool, DataTable> _tuple = new Tuple<bool, DataTable>(false, null);
                return _tuple;
            }
        }
```

This is my frontend, where I retrieve the data that I get from my backend. As you can see, I'm using  `if(this.isAuthorized)`, but right now it doesn't make sense, since I get a tuple, instead of just a boolean. I tried doing `data[0]` for example, but that doesn't do anything, and when I do `data` I get `[Object object]` as result.

```
  Login()
  {
    this.geb={
      Email: this.formModel.Email,
      Wachtwoord: this.formModel.Password
    }
    this.Auth.Login(this.geb).subscribe(data => {
      this.isAuthorized = data
      this.Auth.Authorize(this.isAuthorized);
      if(this.isAuthorized){this.router.navigate(['profile']), 
      this.loggedUser.Email = this.formModel.Email,
      this.loggedUser.Password = this.formModel.Password,
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.loggedUser))
      
    }})}
```

So my question is, how do I retrieve a specific return value from my tuple that comes from the backend?

Comment: Your code is exposed to SQL injection attacks! **NEVER** concatenate sql queries like that! use SqlParameters instead

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

Tuple uses properties Item1, Item2 .... ItemN to access the values , in your case you should map like follows
this.isAuthorized = data.item1

**Recommendation:**

**1: use named tupples**, this is more clear and readable

```
// Tuple<bool, DataTable> 
public (bool isAuthorized, DataTable data) Post(Gebruikers geb) {...}
```

in your front code you can access the values using `isAuthorized` and `data` instead of `item1` and `item2`

**2: use a specific class** (Dto,ViewModel, Response or what ever naming you find your self confortable with

```
public MyPostResponse Post(Gebruikers geb) {...}

public class MyPostResponse 
{
     public bool IsAuthorized {get; set;} 
     public DataTable Data {get; set;}
 }
```